# swift uiwebview a target blank link safari

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview

I just want to open the links with the target blank feature in safari. But with this code blog, all links open in safari. swift and iOS 11.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tarayici: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 let url = URL(string:"http://www.website.com/ios.html")
    tarayici.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
    self.tarayici.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(request.url!)
        return false
    } 
    return true
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still do not get results. Are you sharing information.